# How do you read the address "Harbor Dr. 182"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, pronunciation

How do you read the address "Harbor Dr. 182"? I think it's Drive or Driveway. Is this a small street or a dead end ally or the front of someone's house?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every country has its own street addressing scheme, sometimes more than one, and abbreviation conventions may also vary. What country is this address for?

Comment: It was in an English text book. It's addressed for the United States.

Answer (score 2):

> Harbor Dr. 182

is read "Harbor Drive 182".

A

> drive

is of indeterminate length and size, but usually larger than an "*alley*" and smaller than an "*avenue*".  In the US, the number usually comes before the street designation

> 182 Harbor Dr.

**Driveway** is never used in an address, since a driveway is an access road off of a more *main* road, and the address is always associated with the *main* road (which usually will appear on maps).

Other abbreviations which may be used

> Harbor St - *Harbor Street*
>   Harbor Ct - *Harbor Court*
>   Harbor Rd - *Harbor Road*
>   Harbor Ave - *Harbor Avenue*
>   Harbor Cl - *Harbor Close*
>   Harbor Sq - *Harbor Square*
>   Harbor Cir - *Harbor Circle*
>   Harbor Circ - *Harbor Circus*
>   Harbor Gdn - *Harbor Garden*
>   Harbor Pl - *Harbor Place*

Comment: As well as **Trl**, **Ter**, and **Blvd** for _Trail, Terrace,_ and _Boulevard_, respectively. A more exhaustive list can be found [here](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm). It might also be worth pointing out that some of these are typified by certain features (a _Court_ often dead-ends at a cul-de-sac, for example), though variants probably exist from city to city.